# Connecting to a JMX enabled application behind nginx reverse-proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy, jmx

We are running n dockerized java application on a host. To be more flexible we decided to use Consul as a service registry to easily expose services from the app itself. Services and also JMX metrics (both http) are exposed through a nginx reverse-proxy (config is generated by consul-template).

Now we have the need to connect to a specific container via JMX (SimpleJMX is implemented) to manage beans. Only ports from nginx and consul containers are exposed to the host.

How can I connect to a specific container through nginx? Is there any other option?